# Is it faster to remove all n elements from a Queue or a Priority Queue?

Tags: data-structures, queue, priority-queue

As title suggests, which would be faster and whats the reasoning for it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you empty each element individually, it would be from a queue, since popping from the front is `O(1)` time per element while it's `O(logN)` per element for a priority queue.